# Id for setInterval. How does it work?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an array that stores all my ids used for `setInterval`.

What if I want to create an id, dynamically... can I do like this?

```
id_array.push(++id_var) = setInterval(function, milliseconds);
```

See?

I also have a variable, called 'id_var', that I believe, if I increment it, it will give me, a new 'id'.

Is this code correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id_array.push(setInterval(function, milliseconds));`

or use an object:

```
var obj = {};

obj[++id_var] = setInterval(function, milliseconds);
```

to clear all:

```
for( var id in obj ){
clearInterval( obj[id] );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The return value from `setInterval()` is an opaque token. You just store it somewhere until you want to remove the interval timer with `clearInterval()`.

You cannot control the value of what you receive, nor can you do any kind of arithmetic on it. Just store it and retrieve it.

Answer (score 3):

No. You must use the one that is returned from `setInterval` if you want to call `clearInterval`. You aren't storing that at all.